# Getting the limit of integral of $cos^{2n}(\pi f(x))$ with n→∞

Tags: calculus

Let f be a measurable function on [0, ∞) and such that f(x) ∈ Z iff x ∈ [0, 1]

Evaluate

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^\infty cos^{2n}(\pi f(x))dx$$

Does anyone know how shall I deal with f(x) part to solve its limit? (And where to begin)

Comment: This is quite a beautiful integral. Anyway a few comments: $$$$ -Do you mean the limit variable to be $n$ and not $x$ ? $$$$ -What is $\cos(\pi \cdot \text{integer})$ ? How about $\cos^{2n}(\pi\cdot\text{integer})$ ? $$$$ -What range of values does $\cos^2(\pi z)$ fall into when $z$ is not an integer?

Comment: -oh it's supposed to be n, my bad. Edited

-From what I've been working on, $cos(\pi \cdot integer)$ =1 if the integer is even and -1 if the integer is odd and $cos^{2n}(\pi \cdot integer)$ should be equal to 1 (if I'm correct)

- Also from my work, the range of $cos^{2n}(\pi z)$ should fall between (0,1)

Comment: @Mingg Include your work in your question body to improve your questions's quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^\infty \cos^{2n}(\pi f(x))dx 
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\int_0^1 \cos^{2n}(\pi f(x))dx + \int_{1}^\infty \cos^{2n}(\pi f(x))dx \right) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_0^1 1dx + \int_1^\infty\cos^{2n}(\pi f(x))dx\right) \\
&= 1 + \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty\cos^{2n}(\pi f(x))dx \\
&\overset*= 1 + \int_1^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty}\cos^{2n}(\pi f(x))dx \\
&= 1\end{align}$$
where $(*)$ is by [Beppo Levi's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi%27s_lemma).

Comment: May I know how $\lim_{n \to \infty} cos^{2n} (\pi f(x))$ became 0 from 1 to infinity? This is the part where I’m stuck with..

Comment: @Mingg What is the pointwise limit of that functional sequence?

Comment: From what I’ve got I have f(x)= 1 if x ∈ ℤ and 0 if x ∈ ℝ \ ℤ. I’m not sure if this is correct though..

Comment: @Mingg Yes, correct (but not the name $f$ this time :)). Which one is the limit when $x \in (1,\infty)$?

Comment: My guess would be zero. If that’s the case, how come that f(x) ∈ ℝ \ ℤ when x ∈ (1, ∞)?

Comment: $f(x)$ is not integer when $x\in(1, \infty)$ so $\cos^{2n}(\pi f(x)) \in (0,1)$ when $x\in(1, \infty)$. Since $\lim a^n = 0$ if $a \in (0, 1)$, the pointwise limit is $0$ when $x\in(1, \infty)$. So $$\int_1^\infty\lim \cos^{2n}(\pi f(x)) dx = \int_1^\infty 0dx = 0$$

Comment: Okay I get it now Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Mingg Great. Wouldn't you mind accepting the answer then? :)

Comment: Oh! my bad I thought I already did it.